# Sort list of dictionaries based on relative time

Tags: python, csv, natural-sort, natsort

I have a CSV file that I create from an API response. I get it unsorted and the API response does not have a query parameter to sort the returned payload. The CSV looks like below, where column A has some device identifiers and column B has the configuration last sync of these devices. The time is represented in relative time as seen in the screenshot.

[image: CSV file]

How can I naturally sort the CSV file to have the rows ordered in the following sequence `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days`, `weeks`, `months`, `years`, and `Never`?

I have tried to sort the entries using `natsort` but I didn't get what I am trying to achieve:

```py
import csv
import os

from natsort import natsort, natsort_keygen

natsort_key = natsort_keygen(key=lambda k: k["last_sync"])

fieldnames = ["device", "last_sync"]
with open("Devices_161846.csv", "rt") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(f=csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    next(csvreader)
    identities = list(csvreader)
    sorted_identities = natsort.natsorted(identities, key=natsort_key)

new_file, ext = os.path.splitext(csvfile.name)
with open(f"{new_file}_Sorted.{ext}", "wt") as f:
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(f=f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    csvwriter.writerows(sorted_identities)
```

I expect to get the same result, but sorted from newest to oldest.

Comment: What about `2 seconds ago` (*if it exists*) and `a few seconds ago`? Which one should come first?

Comment: @Timeless I don't get the number of seconds until it is `a minute ago`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`parse`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dateparser.html#dateparser.freshness_date_parser.FreshnessDateDataParser.parse) from [dateparser](/questions/tagged/dateparser) as a sorting key, this way :

```
# pip install dateparser
import csv, datetime, dateparser

def parse(st):
    if st == "Never": return datetime.datetime.min
    else:
        if (dt:=dateparser.parse(st.replace("a few", "0"))):
            return dt
        else:
            return datetime.datetime.now()

header = ["device", "last_sync"]

with (
    open("/Devices_161846.csv", "r") as inpf,
    open("Devices_161846_Sorted.csv", "w", newline="") as outf
):
    reader = csv.DictReader(inpf, fieldnames=header)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=header)
    
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(
        sorted(reader, key=lambda x: parse(x["last_sync"]), reverse=True)
    )
```

Output (*Devices_161846_Sorted.csv*) :

```
device,last_sync
j,a few seconds ago
f,29 minutes ago
g,38 minutes ago
c,an hour ago
a,an hour ago
d,13 hours ago
h,a day ago
e,4 days ago
b,17 days ago
i,Never
```

Input used (*Devices_161846.csv*) :

```
a,an hour ago
b,17 days ago
c,an hour ago
d,13 hours ago
e,4 days ago
f,29 minutes ago
g,38 minutes ago
h,a day ago
i,Never
j,a few seconds ago
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You literally saved the day <3 (Y)